# Import remote sql.gz file to ClearDB database

Tags: sql, heroku, mysql, cleardb

I have a large database dump on some server, for example:

```
http://url.to/database.sql.gz
```

and want to import it to ClearDB. It's quite large file, and I would like to do this without downloading and uploading that file again.

Note that I don't have access to the old database, just this file. The new database is used with Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

From the console where do you have the file do

```
root@server# mysql -h us-cdbr-azure-west-b.cleardb.com -u usernmae -p database < file.sql
```

The prompt will ask for password then the file will load from local server to the cleardb server.

If you want to send the process to the background using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then write `bg`.

I load a 3G sql file and work for me. Hope this work for you.